# Install Windows 8 - 30 GB C drive in internal drive and 500 GB external drive

Tags: windows-8, external-hard-drive

I have a tablet that has 30GB internal drive and 500GB external drive. I am unable to install Windows 8 on external drive because of some problems. I am also unable to increase the size of C drive because C drive is on Disk0 and D drive is on Disk 1

What is my solution?

I have 64 GB SD card, I can buy SD card with more space. When I put SD card inside it, I get 64 GB another partition.

Can I install Windows 8 on SD Card.

How can I increase my C Drive. Is there any software solution or should I go to hardware market and ask them to remove my 30 GB internal drive and insert like some 500 GB internal drive.

Comment: The simple solution, delete both partitions, then install Windows on the unallocated space on the storage device.  You will be unable to install Windows on your external (SD Card) storage device.

Comment: I think that he is eqquiped with some 32GB storage, because he said, C is Disk 0 (aka 32GB) and D is Disk1 (500GB External). Can you precise what storage do you have OP so we can give you more precise advises ? Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here is my Tablet model number ---------------YIIB Haier Intel® Core™ M-5Y10c----------------This is the PDF link about this tablet. --------http://www.haier.com/bigfiles/directory/cn/Notebook/20150612/bf1518814998.pdf    --------Thank you.

Comment: Wait. A table as in PixelSense? You do know that operating system doesn't go into the table itself, right?

Comment: Sorry, it was a tablet. I rectified the mistake. Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to run windows on an SD card isn't a good idea, since they are not made for intensive I/O and will have low performance.
I would highly advice you not to try that.

If you are willing to do it, you can test the speed by setting-up and running a Windows-to-go on that SD card and boot from it.

We tested on lab an USB 3.0 64gig stick windows to go install and it was incredibly slow and unresponsive.

The best solution for you is to swap the 32GB drive you have in your tablet and replace it with a proper drive. If this is not possible, try to see if you can add another drive (M2/mSATA) and use it as a system drive.

edit: after providing us the PDF manual of the laptop, we can ensure that the SSD is a **Liteon CS1-SP32 (M2-2240 format)**
I would recommend buying a new M2 drive with proper capacity (no lower that 128GB for OS drive) you can aim for instance this drive : Transcend TS128GMTS400.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please check my comment in the original post that provides information about my Tablet. This is the link to PDF about its specifications ------- http://www.haier.com/bigfiles/directory/cn/Notebook/20150612/bf1518814998.pdf

Comment: The internal LiteOn CP32SP M2 2240 SSD is removable, open the laptop, switch it with a proper 128GB SSD (Transcend TS128GMTS400 for instance) and enjoy the proper performance + space :) will edit my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. It will help me get going.